# What is the difference between these two functions, so that type hinting works correctly in one, and not in the other?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type payloadCollection = {
    [key in string]: any
}

type bHardcodedPayload = {
    b: string
}

class A<TListeners extends payloadCollection = any> {
    /** Two param overriden function */
    twoParamOverride<T extends keyof TListeners>(listenerName: T, secondParameter: string): void;
    twoParamOverride(listenerName: 'disconnect', secondParameter: number): void;
    twoParamOverride(listenerName: string, secondParameter: string | number): void {}

    oneParamOverride<T extends keyof TListeners>(listenerName: T): void;
    oneParamOverride(listenerName: 'disconnect'): void;
    oneParamOverride(listenerName: string): void {}
}

class B<TListeners extends payloadCollection = any> extends A<TListeners & bHardcodedPayload> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        /** Type hinting (CTRL+Space inside the string) only shows the second override of this function for the first parameter, 
         * "disconnect", instead of validly hinting that the first parameter could either be "disconnect" or "b" */
        this.twoParamOverride('');

        /** Type hinting correctly identifies that the only parameter for the function can be either "b" or "disconnect" */
        this.oneParamOverride('b');
    }
}
```

My expectation would be for type hinting to work correctly on both cases, as the second parameter is dependent on the first, and the first parameter can be more then `disconnect` only. **Why does it work as expected on the single parameter function, and not on the two parameter one?**

[Fiddle here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGIBsD2sAmBhJCEQMbAEskA7KAXigG8AoKOqAbQGsIQoDSBnYAJw4HMAugC4osYiGoBfatVCQoAIwASsHqlxJUEVAAV4yNOSq16i0dz7F%2002bgSxOnKAEEAPABUAMgW4RiEDzOEAAewP6oznCIKBhYOPhEpBTiIAB8JvRQAPQAVLlQHgDuSDBqsAC2UEgAboF82qQAZgCuxIkkULnZ1ACQwCX6PJUA8nU8DRCeUKHhxJFQLCBITYU%20fgFBaQAUCL5zgQBylRCiHgA0UJx4JHrlFRDhPBa8AgCUojVIBKgA3H0DJBDUbjSa7fb%20I4nUQAclQvk0xAC%20Bhl2uiLuwweT1ExBaFUUgQ%20UC%20P3%20-UG9zG9R%20EHBGyhDxeVn4aJu82B2MCzIEUAAPlA8QSiZ9vqgqDJTHQSBBOdSJrTprMIs4lis1hDNpwdnsGTxjkzCsTSX8pdUAnLQbT6Qd9dCoHCESRkcAYcaxf8sjLLTTtDbIXbDZZ3qKfhLbNR7I5nAAhTzrW3BMIqsoxNCYbB4QidFISDLK%20bOdzeTWBZwAMiUqnUmm0dzTqAyNCyiMsLXwSB42zemSy9E4LUgXbe-zNWTyBQ84GgAAsOIRrFBtugPAAlLwAagAynBcNAOJxaVBgDPoMHrD2SAg2JwZ0gis4T2f2eLar7oOqT74oK12tnmp2x6nj%20BBBMAZRYo8gSXGOWQFAARPCnCIi68GXAe4RGOqNSwHsqDXlAc7EAu-BAbA4FPiBYEQScTxQJoLQIOKEAEE%20PBKNAiFOkiWbwdU7HwYofHdLBdBfpwAB0gI%20gqfowm6o59vQE6FNOhHzrymgTFmBG0sRBBNAQECPjO5FAR%20xAEXAkF0U0gGUb%20HSkLg4gcTMrGngJQn8VAXHIc6vFdD0SliXOknelSVpyYoClmjIkoqQAsmwoSQPg5FJFAJSMeKhI-vZalESRx6lCUPBMPRnY8DpbCdIoSAnvRjjGZcjjmVcL40Vy7HftokDzP44GdA5oHcK18ztYZ1G0AUXVQexLmkHlFSdtAT6kH5KGBVeIASVAADqM5sKgSDGew4FlRVbWpVmOjmu1h7WDgc22W0TnjeKxANfdlGAi9gTmhAAD8QVAA)

Comment: I'd say this is a TS bug or limitation.  It's similar to [ms/TS#43915](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43915) and [ms/TS#44183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44183) .  Unfortunately I don't have an authoritative answer since I haven't found the exact scenario here listed in a GitHub issue.  So what would you like to see as an answer to this question?  Conjecture that it's a bug?  Or no answer at all? Or maybe you might decide to open a new properly-formatted GitHub issue asking about this and link to them, and then use the response there to answer this?

Comment: I am planning on opening a github issue, just wanted to make sure, that it is not me, that is missing something obvious, and this indeed is or seems like a bug.